# what does "⨀" mean when used on complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, fractals

So I was watching codeparade on youtube, when I saw that their "feather fractal" they created used the $\odot$ symbol in the context: $z\odot z$. When I searched it up, it said it is the "Hadamard product". The issue is that the Hadamard product is defined on matrices and vectors, not complex numbers.
I found out that you can represent complex numbers as matrices, so I thought that's how it worked, but I realized it's probably not so because there's no way to convert a matrix back into a complex number.
I tried searching for a long time, but i didn't find anything that helps. thank you for the help!
This is [the video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiAj9WW1OfQ&t=8s&ab_channel=CodeParade) and the feather fractal is shown at 5:18.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If I had to guess what "Hadamard product of complex numbers" meant I would guess it means $(a + bi) \odot (c + di) = ac + bdi$; that is, the Hadamard product thinking of them as vectors. That's a strange operation though.

Comment: I don't know about this notation. However, if it is the Hadamard product, then one can apply it to complex numbers, by considering $z=x+iy = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: i'll try it out

Comment: it seems to have worked! i'll try zooming in to see if it looks like the fractal shown

Comment: it is the fractal shown in the video! however, my coloring system doesn't seem to be the same as codeparade's... thanks for the help though!